# Index.html is not my default page (somehow my wiki overwrote it)

Tags: html, .htaccess, mediawiki

I installed mediawiki on my website. I had a problem where my wiki pages started with www.mywebsite/mywiki/index.php/mywikipage. I wanted to get rid off this "index.php" so I made short url to my wiki with this website: http://shorturls.redwerks.org/. From here I got one code to .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

And another what went to LocalSettings.php in my wiki folder:

```
## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs please see:
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads  = true;
$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse = false;
```

After this I had no more problem with the URL of my wiki pages. But my website front page goes to wiki now. I want it back to index.html. I tried to put this code into my .htaccess file but still doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The rule is currently rewriting homepage to /w/index.php

Change this :

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html [L]
```

so that a request for hompage can internally redirect to /index.html

Comment: It didn't help. Also when I wanted to click on a page on my wiki it gave me this: http://i.imgur.com/ZC2hgaQ.png

This is my actual website (without styling and other visual things).